# create a war file using git

Tags: git, maven, deployment

I usually use a maven project to create a war file

`(Maven Clean -> Maven Install)`. War file is created under target folder.

Now, I am using git for my repository.

Is there a way we can use Git for creating a war file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is not.

git is a version control system and Maven is a build tool. They are of different concepts and completely different use-case.